# How would I decrypt multiple messages at once?

Tags: java, android, performance, encryption, aes

TLDR; In Java using AES cryptography, how do I pack encrypted messages together to decrypt with a single decryption call?

I am using AES cryptography in an android chat application, and when decrypting multiple messages (using the same key), the program becomes very slow to the the point where I have to use multithreading so it does not freeze the system.

I understand there is a way to pack encrypted messages together to decrypt them all at once which should be much faster, but I cannot find anything online about how to do this in Java/Kotlin. The only way I can think to do this is append the plaintext together with delimiters and encrypt it, but I would need to change my database to store a single record that contains a large text field, and my professor explicitly stated that changes cannot be made after week 4, and it is week 6. Is there any other way I can achieve this with a list of already encrypted messages?

Edit - Here is the decryption function that is called for each message:

```
    private String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secretKey, String username) {
    try {
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), username.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec newSecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newSecretKey, ivspec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: There's no reason you should be having these performance problems unless you have some serious design issues with your crypto, and decrypting "multiple" messages at once will likely not fix the design issues. Without actual code showing the problem areas we can't really help

Comment: I made an edit to add my decryption function, but I am not quite sure what you mean because decryption is always a performance-heavy task. I think it makes sense that calling it many times would be slow but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are performing the deliberately expensive key derivation function on every decrypt. Presumably you spend 99% of the time in `generateSecret` and 1% in `doFinal`. Since `secretKey` and `username` are likely to be the same for multiple messages, you should derive the key once and use the cached key as long as the secret key and username remain the same. Of course, the real problem with your code then becomes obvious: you are using the same derived-key/iv pair for more than one message. You should be using a random IV for each message.

Comment: Thank you so much! If you post that as the answer, I will mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password-based key derivation functions are designed to be expensive (to prevent brute-forcing), yet you are preforming that expensive function on every decrypt.

The key derivation will predominate your run time. The AES portion is likely tiny. Since `secretKey` and `username` are likely to be the same for multiple messages, you should derive the key once and use the cached key as long as the secret key and username remain the same.